# How to recover text spaces after changing it using tokens?

Tags: python, function, text

I've got original text and its tokens:
Example:

```
original_text = "  Genius,     scientist and my friend - John"
text_tokens = ["Genius", ",", "scientist", "and", "my", "friend", "-", "John"]
```

I'm changin' tokens:
For example:

```
Genius -> <spam>Genius</spam>
```

I need to recover text including **SPACES**.
How I can do that?
Result should be like that:

```
"  <spam>Genius</spam>,     scientist and my friend - John"
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep tracking what tokens need to be changed, and replace them in the original string.

```
new_text = original_text
replacements = {'Genius': '<spam>Genius</spam>'}
for orig in replacements:
  new_text = new_text.replace(orig, replacements[orig])
```